# QueryDSL: DateTimePath to formatted string

Tags: java, date, jpql, querydsl

I need to compare date with string using "like" in querydsl. So I need to convert datetimepath to string in specific format. In my case it's "MM/dd/yyyy"
Something like that:

```
String dateString = "%20/2015%";
QueryBase whereClause = query.where(myEntity.date.toString("MM/dd/yyyy").like(dateString));
```

myEntity.date is `DateTimePath<java.util.Date>`
Any ideas how to represent it as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that I've found is to use native function (MySql in my case).
Something like this:

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("DATE_FORMAT({0}, {1})", myEntity.date, "%m/%d/%Y")
           .likeIgnoreCase(dateString);
```

Comment: Hi. Have you found a non native way to do exactly this?? Because one drawback of this is when you change database it could break!

Comment: @Merv nope, I didn't, unfortunately. Yeah, it could break. It is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static BooleanExpression getValue(DateTimePath<DateTime> inputDatePath, String ep){
    return inputDatePath.month().stringValue()
            .concat("/")
            .concat(inputDatePath.dayOfMonth().stringValue())
            .concat("/")
            .concat(inputDatePath.year().stringValue())
            .contains(ep); 
}   

query.where(getValue(myEntity.date , "11/20/2015"));
```

Comment: This won't work for the date format in the question, where month is 2 digits, and day of the month is also 2 digits.